# Listview with Images in SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

So I have a listview inside of one of three tabs. I'm using SherlockListFragment for the listview, and it's working fine. The only thing I just am so lost with, is how to add images to the listview from a string-array.

Here is the activity with the listview:

```
public class CurrentMobs extends SherlockListFragment{

    private static final int ACTIVITY_0 = 0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1; 
    private static final int ACTIVITY_2 = 2;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_3 = 3;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_4 = 4;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_5 = 5;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_6 = 6;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_7 = 7;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_8 = 8;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_9 = 9;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_10 = 10;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_11 = 11;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_12 = 12;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_13 = 13;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_14 = 14;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_15 = 15;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_16 = 16;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_17 = 17;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_18 = 18;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_19 = 19;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_20 = 20;

    @Override
      public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] commands  = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currentmobs_selections);
        String[] commandsImages = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currentmobs_selections);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.main_list_item, commands);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
            switch (position)
            {
            case ACTIVITY_0:
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Bat.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_1:
                Intent i1 = new Intent(getActivity(),Blaze.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_2:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(getActivity(),CaveSpider.class);
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_3:
                Intent i3 = new Intent(getActivity(),Creeper.class);
                startActivity(i3);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_4:
                Intent i4 = new Intent(getActivity(),EnderDragon.class);
                startActivity(i4);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_5:
                Intent i5 = new Intent(getActivity(),Endermen.class);
                startActivity(i5);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_6:
                Intent i6 = new Intent(getActivity(),Ghast.class);
                startActivity(i6);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_7:
                Intent i7 = new Intent(getActivity(),IronGolem.class);
                startActivity(i7);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_8:
                Intent i8 = new Intent(getActivity(),MagmaCube.class);
                startActivity(i8);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_9:
                Intent i9 = new Intent(getActivity(),SilverFish.class);
                startActivity(i9);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_10:
                Intent i10 = new Intent(getActivity(),Skeleton.class);
                startActivity(i10);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_11:
                Intent i11 = new Intent(getActivity(),Slime.class);
                startActivity(i11);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_12:
                Intent i12 = new Intent(getActivity(),SnowGolem.class);
                startActivity(i12);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_13:
                Intent i13 = new Intent(getActivity(),Spider.class);
                startActivity(i13);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_14:
                Intent i14 = new Intent(getActivity(),SpiderJockey.class);
                startActivity(i14);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_15:
                Intent i15 = new Intent(getActivity(),Villager.class);
                startActivity(i15);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_16:
                Intent i16 = new Intent(getActivity(),Witch.class);
                startActivity(i16);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_17:
                Intent i17 = new Intent(getActivity(),Wither.class);
                startActivity(i17);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_18:
                Intent i18 = new Intent(getActivity(),WitherSkeleton.class);
                startActivity(i18);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_19:
                Intent i19 = new Intent(getActivity(),Zombie.class);
                startActivity(i19);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY_20:
                Intent i20 = new Intent(getActivity(),ZombiePigman.class);
                startActivity(i20);
                break;
            }
      }
```

Currently, commandsImages isn't being used, cause I just don't know where to fit it in to add the images to the listview. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First of all try to use BaseAdapter. In your getview inflate a view that has in ImageView in it. then create your data since keelping bitmaps in memory is really heavy, Try using DiskLruCache for it. Or best possible way is read your bitmaps compress each into an JPEG memorystream, Keeping these in memory should be fine. then in getview use either Cache or memorystream array to get your bitmaps and set them on imageview

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? That sounds extremely confusing yo me, cause I'm a noon at this.

Comment: hmmmm i guess using iamges in listview is not simple, having other UI is easy. start with BaseAdapter, then with DiskLruCache it would not be difficult